# Counting paragraphs with Golang?

Tags: go, count, readfile

**However little known the feelings or views of such a man may be on his
first entering a neighbourhood, this truth is so well fixed in the minds
of the surrounding families, that he is considered the rightful property
of some one or other of their daughters.**

**My dear Mr. Bennet," said his lady to him one day, "have you heard that
Netherfield Park is let at last?**

**Mr. Bennet replied that he had not.**

```
func readBook(filePath string) {
     dat , err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
     check(err)
     book := string(dat)
     fmt.Print("paragraph : ",strings.Count(book,"\n\n"))
}
```

I am trying but I cant .That is return '0'. I want '3'. How can I count paragraphs ?

Comment: Add `fmt.Printf("%q\n", dat)` to confirm that the paragraphs are separated by exactly two newlines.  Also, the application is counting separators, not paragraphs. The number of paragraphs is one plus the number of separators.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thank you very much. Its working now. I changed "\n\n" > "\n\r\n".